# Why is my gatsby activeStyle only taking effect when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, styles, gatsby

I am hoping that someone could possibly help me.

I'm tryng to make my navigation links active in Gatsby. So I'm using Link with activeStyle. And for some reason it is not working. If I refresh the page the active style takes effect on the current page. But every time I change the page I have to refresh again.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import "../components/styles/navigation.module.css"

const Navigation = ({ menuLinks }) => {
return (
<header>
<div className="container">
<div>
<nav>
<ul>
{menuLinks.map(link => (
<li
key={link.name}
>
<Link activeStyle={{color: "black"}} className="nav-links" to={link.link}>
{link.name}
</Link>
</li>
))}
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</header>
)
}

export default Navigation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake on my part. My NPM packages and Gatsby were extremely out of date. I updated NPM Packages and Gatsby and now it works like it should.